# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open an Image from the gallery and place a random rectangle on it. But when I click the button to open the gallery, the following exception occurs.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 TextView textView;
 ImageView image1;
Button get_image, save_image, read_image;
 String selectedImagePath;
int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
String DB_NAME =  "test.db";
String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
String pts_table="ptstable";
Bitmap bmp;
Intent intent;
Canvas cnvs;
Uri selectedImageUri;
Random r;
int x,y;
Paint paint;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    r=new Random();

    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    get_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_image);
    get_image.setOnClickListener(this);

    save_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_image);
    save_image.setOnClickListener(this);

    read_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read_image);
    read_image.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {

    case R.id.get_image:

        intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
         SELECT_PICTURE);
        break;
    }

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && data!=null) {

            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);

            bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(image1.getHeight(),image1.getWidth(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            cnvs=new Canvas(bmp);
            paint=new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            cnvs.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath), 0,0,null);
            cnvs.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100, paint);
            image1.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            //image1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

}

This occurs inside onActivityResult() at

```
bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getHeight(),img.getWidth(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: `img.getHeight()` and `img.getWidth()` are returning `0`

Comment: Yes. But I dont know how to initialize to a new bitmap other than this

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add some defense code for checking whether the return data is available for your next action but not use it immediately.

Somehow, because of the varies of android devices, the return data is not always the right one in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, getActivity());
Bitmap bm;
BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
img.setImageBitmap(bm);
uploadImagePath = tempPath;
```

Hope this will helps you..